# Conditionally changing elements of Pandas Dataframe in a more Pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas

Given aaa,bbb,pos are equally sized dataframes

I was wondering if there was a more pythoninc way to do the follow:

```
for x in range(1, len(aaa)):
    for y in range(0, len(aaa.columns)):
        if aaa.iloc[x,y]>bbb.iloc[x,y] and aaa.iloc[x-1,y]<bbb.iloc[x,y]:
            pos.iloc[x-1,y]=12
```

Comment: Do you mean `pos = 12 if aaa > bbb and lag(aaa) < ccc else pos` ?

Comment: Are you looking for a Python + NumPy solution, or a plain Python solution?  What are the types of `aaa`, `bbb`, etc. in Python land?

Comment: @BhargavRao: I'm guessing that lag is this: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lag.html

Comment: Okay; that makes this more of a Pandas question than a pure Python question.  I've edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: Sorry Mark, numpy would be good too. pos, aaa,bbb,ccc are pandas dataframes of dates and prices. There are several columns and hundreds of rows of dates. lag is the R equivalent of Python .shift(-1)

Comment: Can you post data and desired output, it's difficult to post an answer based on something so vague

Comment: I added a potential output

Comment: Simplified the question to a pure python/pandas question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, all you need to do is build a mask and shift it:

```
mask = ((aaa > bbb) & (aaa.shift() < bbb))
mask = mask.shift(-1).fillna(False)
pos[mask] = 12
```

For example:

```
>>> aaa
          0         1         2         3
0 -1.247550  0.456291 -0.185969 -0.675125
1 -0.495517 -1.451255  0.862562 -1.064612
2  1.026445  0.180647 -0.153980  0.685134
>>> bbb
          0         1         2         3
0  0.731204  1.241322  0.594712 -0.166606
1 -0.067717  0.207725  0.021185 -0.893406
2  0.656187 -0.536448 -0.292571 -0.586492
>>> mask
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False   True  False
1   True   True  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
>>> orig(aaa,bbb,pos)
    0   1   2   3
0   0   0  12   0
1  12  12   0  12
2   0   0   0   0
>>> new
    0   1   2   3
0   0   0  12   0
1  12  12   0  12
2   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Yes that works.  Thank you.  Why do you use the "&" vs. "and".  My problem is that I was using the "and" and getting an ambiguity error "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: @PaulO: that's because Python's `and` can't be modified, and it's trying to convert an vector object -- which could be something like `[True, True, False]` to a boolean, and as the error message says that's ambiguous.